# Efficient colorization of numpy matrix by value?

Tags: python, colors, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray that looks something like:

```
[[0, 0.25, 1,  ...., 0.5, 0.23 ],
 [0.3, 0.75, 1, ..., 0.5, 0.37 ],
  ...,
  ...,
 [0, 0.25, 1,  ...., 0.5, 0.23 ],
 [0.3, 0.75, 1, ..., 0.5, 0.37 ]]
```

Basically every value is in the range 0 - 1.0

I would like to visualize this as a bitmap and currently I have a very slow loop which basically does this:

```
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        yield val_to_rgb(val)
```

It then will take the 3-tuple of rgb components and do a PIL putdata on it and create a PNG.

I need to do this many times and this ghetto method is slow, and the colorization is very ugly.

My question is this:

Is there a series of matrix operations I can apply which will yield a colorized matrix containing the raw RGB values?

Which really consists of two questions:

1. What is the most efficient transformation I can apply to get RGB tuples from the above matrix
2. Is there a "nice" way to convert (0, 1.0) values into a colorized representation?

Edit: Clarification- I'm looking to SAVE this as PNG, not just view it in real time. The reason being that a lot of this is getting executed on a headless machine which I then inspect after the fact.

The output of the current algo looks pretty nasty:

[image: Colorized Matrix]

Comment: It would really help to know what your `val_to_rgb` function does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

matplotlib has [imshow](http://matplotlib.org/users/image_tutorial.html) function you can use out-of-the-box.

What you're doing is usually done via "vectorization". You define a function and let numpy do the iteration:

```
vec = np.vectorize(val_to_rgb)
rgb_data = vec(data)
```

Comment: `np.vectorize` and the like are just syntactic sugar: they make your code look nicer, but the loops are still running in python, so there is no performance advantage.

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't seem to be suitable for applications on headless machines. I'm running heavy parallelization and at least on OSX I'm getting errors related to trying to use core image functionality from a daemonized process. It seems like this library is built more for real-time inspection of datasets.

Comment: @amirpc matplotlib is no problem on headless machines... you just need to change backends to use a purely non-gui one.

Comment: @seberg - so it does. I've gotten it working with an svg backend and it seems to be running great, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Is OOTB same as out of the box?

Answer (score 2):

I am not very familiar with PIL, but I am guessing that it will swallow a numpy array of shape `(rows, cols, 3)` and turn it into an image. So you want to rewrite your `val_to_rgb` function so that it works with arrays, not scalars, and places the RGB values in the last dimension of the shape.

E.g., say you wanted to interpret your values as grayscale, 0 being black, 1 being white. Your current function taking scalar inputs would look like this:

```
def val_to_rgb(val) :
    return (int(val * 255),) * 3
```

and a vectorized form would be something like:

```
def vals_to_rgbs(vals) :
    ret = np.zeros(vals.shape + (3,),  dtype='uint8')
    ret[...] = vals.reshape(vals.shape + (1,)) * 255
    return ret

>>> vals_to_rgb(np.random.rand(10,10)).shape
(10, 10, 3)
>>> vals_to_rgb(np.random.rand(10,10)).dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

where the reshape is to have broadcasting do its magic.

Thinks can get more complicated, so if you need help vectorizing your specific `val_to_rgb` function, post your code and I'll gladly take a shot at it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're saying here. It seems like what you're saying is I can stick an extra piece of data in each cell which is a 3 component list of RGB values, is that correct? If that is so, what is the reasoning behind doing that?

Comment: @amirpc - His point is that you can just make an MxNx3 array using your colormap (i.e. separate red, green, and blue bands) and PIL will interpret the array as a color image.   If you really want a pure pixel-to-pixel representation (i.e. the exact same number of pixels in the array as in your image), it's faster and a bit simpler to do it this way.  Matplotlib, on the other hand, has a lot more features, and will make using multiple color maps very painless, but "thinks" in a display space that you'll have to jump through a couple of hoops to get to save as pixel-to-pixel representation.